# How to use the aws genarated Android SDK with api gateway

Tags: android, aws-api-gateway, aws-sdk-android

My deployed `AWS API Gateway` has one endpoint:
`/users` with a `DELETE` Method. I'm trying to call this method from my `android app` using a `generated SDK`.
I have deployed the API, then generated the SDK in the API Gateway console and downloaded my zip folder named `aws-apigateway-api-sdk-1.0.0`. I then ran 'mvn install' inside the folder and copied the generated .jar file and libs into my project and added the gradle imports (basically I did everything as in [these instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk-android.html) until point 7).

Now I want to create the SDK in my android code. In the instructions they do it this way:

```
// Create an instance of your SDK. Here, 'SimpleCalcClient.java' is the compiled java class for the SDK generated by API Gateway.
final SimpleCalcClient client = factory.build(SimpleCalcClient.class);
```

My problem is this `SimpleCalcClient.class` -> I know I need to replace this with my own value, but in my generated target folder I only found following class named `LambdaSimpleProxyClient.class`, which is an interface. This doesnt seem to be the right class though:

[image: The generated LambdaSimpleProxyClient.class]

I still tried to use the `ApiClientFactory` with this class, right now my code looks like this:

```
public void deleteUser(View view) {
        ApiClientFactory factory = new ApiClientFactory();
        final LambdaSimpleProxyClient client = factory.build(LambdaSimpleProxyClient.class);
        client.usersDelete();
}
```

The `LambdaSimpleProxyClass.java` was generated in step 5 when I ran `mvn install`, it has the method `usersDelete()` in it, which makes sense to me because that fits with how I called my API Endpoint and looks kinda promising, but I don't rally think that's the class I should use here (but there was no other `.class` file in my zip folder that was generated by the `API Gateway Generate SDK Method`:

```
/**
     *
     *
     * @return Empty
     */
    @com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.annotation.Operation(path = "/users", method = "DELETE")
    Empty usersDelete();
```

I also don't understand how to pass my query parameter `username` in here, but I still tried to call this method. The program then crashes at client.usersDelete();

So what else than `LambdaSimpleProxyClient.class` should I use there? There is no other `.class` file in my generated zip folder `aws-apigateway-api-sdk-1.0.0` or in my by maven generated target folder.

```
2020-12-21 20:59:32.427 5340-5340/de.stuttgart.syzl3000 D/ProfileActivity: deleteAccount: delete Btn clicked
2020-12-21 20:59:32.441 5340-5340/de.stuttgart.syzl3000 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-12-21 20:59:32.445 5340-5340/de.stuttgart.syzl3000 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: de.stuttgart.syzl3000, PID: 5340
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
     Caused by: com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientException:  (Service: null; Status Code: 0; Error Code: null; Request ID: null)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientHandler.invoke(ApiClientHandler.java:118)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:913)
        at $Proxy1.usersDelete(Unknown Source)
        at de.stuttgart.syzl3000.menu.ProfileActivity.deleteAccount(ProfileActivity.java:49)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1448)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:102)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:90)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:787)
        at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:175)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:141)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:83)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:174)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseMessage(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:534)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseMessage(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:109)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseMessage(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.createHttpResponse(UrlHttpClient.java:92)
        at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.execute(UrlHttpClient.java:85)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientHandler.invoke(ApiClientHandler.java:109)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:913) 
        at $Proxy1.usersDelete(Unknown Source) 
        at de.stuttgart.syzl3000.menu.ProfileActivity.deleteAccount(ProfileActivity.java:49) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Any hints are welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to run the "Generate SDK" in my API Gateway Console again, because somehow the query parameter that I added wasn't in the deployed version. After deploying it again and generating a new SDK, I moved the unzipped folder `aws-apigateway-api-sdk-1.0.0` into my `app` folder. Then the `LambdaSimpleProxyClient.class` was automatically recognised in the `factory.build(LambdaSimpleProxyClient.class)` call and I was able to pass the query parameter into the `client.deleteUser("<my-username-value>")` method that now accepted a passed in String parameter.

There's still an error, but I'll open a new question for that.